NSScrollView with large content is creating a huge number of tiles upon redraw - in some cases
The main view of my application is an NSScrollView. When the document size is large, say 24k x 17k pixels (approximately 30 x 30 landscape pages), when the magnification of that view changes from normal size (1.0) to a reduced to fit (≈0.05), my [NSView drawRect:] for the view is being called thousands of times for very small tiles.
A single iteration over what needs to be drawn is time-consuming, even when bounds intelligently filtering what needs to be drawn. Thousands of iterations are glacially slow - not tolerable.
This screenshot shows the multitude of tiles, filling each one with a random color.
Screenshot showing the tiny tiles the view is being broken into
An interesting thing is that once it has drawn those thousands of tiles, the NSScrollView no longer tiles the view but instead calls my drawRect: with a rect that covers the whole view.  It seems like it may be a bug with NSScrollView.
In addition, if the magnification only changes in relatively small increments say a factor of 1.5 - 2.0, there is never a proliferation of tiles, but typical-sized tiles.
So, I have two questions:

Is this a bug in NSScrollView?
Is there a way to prevent NSScrollView from tiling its contents?

Here is a paired-down Apple Sample project that demonstrates the issue: Link to my NSTextView example
To see the issue, build the app and run it.  Once running, choose 'Normal Size' from the View menu.  After it refreshes, choose 'Reduce to Fit' from the View menu and you will see that an excessive number of tiles are drawn.

Is the very small tile the same size as the visible rect at magnification 1.0? Are the very small tiles inside the visible part of the view?

How can we reproduce the issue?

@Willeke Unfortunately, there isn't a trivial amount of code I can include in the description to demonstrate the issue.  However, I've taken Apple's NSScrollView example, simplified and mofified it to show the issue.   https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/x0b8px47vbks51vyjdkym/NSScrollViewTest.zip?rlkey=x9hf29xcn4g87pgbkcipxro6u&dl=0
If you build the app, run it, choose Normal Size - you'll see a bunch of tiles.  Choose Reduce to fit - you'll see it draws a zillion tiny tiles.

I don't see any issues on my Mac. Maybe it's settings or hardware related.

@Willeke, after all of the micro tiles are rendered, an additional redraw occurs that overwrites them, thereby obscuring the small tiles.  Set a breakpoint on line 51 of MyVeiw drawRect: so you can catch the issue.  You can also see in the debugging console all of the NSLog(@"drawRect dirtyRect.size: %@", @(dirtyRect.size)); made from drawRect:.   I have tested this example on several machines and on several versions of macOS.  The issue occurs on every machine and macOS I have tested.

I can reproduce the issue on my 2012 Mac with macOS 10.15 but not on my 2023 Mac with macOS 14. There's a tiled layer somewhere. Without the animator it's ok.
